# Laravel Ошибка $order is undefined

Tags: php

PHP - 7.2.34
laravel - 6.2

Выбивает ошибку
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $order }} with {{ $order ?? '' }}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал
php artisan route:clear - проходит
А вот
$ php artisan route:cache - выбивает ошибку

```
   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at D:\programming\OpenServer\domains\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919|
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921|
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Простите, я Вас не понял. Я же вроде и так, написал текстом + приложил скриншот. 
Заранее прошу прощения, я довольно новый пользователь, еще не освоился)

Comment: У вас $order === undefined. А вы у него берете продукты. Это аналог NullPointerException в других языках. Вам надо обработать случай, когда заказа нет.

Comment: @РусланМамедов , можете пожалуйста подсказать как это сделать ?

Comment: @Danil да хотя бы просто поместить весь код цикла в директиву if orders !== undefined.

Comment: @РусланМамедов , спасибо за Ваш ответ, обновил страницу все заработало .
Хотя я ничего не делал.